# Azure REST Call to get enterprise application single sign-on information

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-rest-api

Trying to use the Microsoft graph API to get information about my Enterprise Applications, can get a lot of it via the `applications` and `serviceProviders` calls but I don't see a way to the information for what is available on the `Single sign-on` tab in the Azure portal.

I assumed it was `claimsMappingPolicies` but that always returns an empty list, when doing a `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/serviceProviders/{id}/claimsMappingPolicies` for a particular service provider or just calling `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/claimsMappingPolicies`.

The result is

```
Body:  {"@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#policies/claimsMappingPolicies","value":[]}
```

I've tried all the other policies around the application and serviceProvider with no luck.

Is there another API that I can use to get this information?

For reference here is a screenshot of the information that I'm looking for:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use Microsoft Graph to [configure the SAML-based SSO app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/application-saml-sso-configure-api?tabs=http).

So most SAML-based SSO information endpoints should be available on this page.

I think your concern is how to get the basic user claims.

Unfortunately the data is not exposed by Microsoft Graph. Microsoft Graph can only get the custom claims which you configured with `claimsMappingPolicies`. It means if you configure `claimsMappingPolicies` with Microsoft Graph, you can get it with Microsoft Graph.

If you update the user attributes and claims on Azure portal, you will find it's calling this endpoint:

`POST https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api/ApplicationSso/{service principal object id}/FederatedSsoClaimsPolicyV2`

which is different with Microsoft Graph.

So I'm afraid that MS doesn't exposed an API to do this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, not the one I was hoping for but kind-of expected it.