# Missing information (SAML, OAuth) on Applications integrated with Azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to export all applications configurations. To do that I used the following commands :

```
Get-AzureADApplication ; Get-AzureADServicePrincipal ; Get-MgApplication ; Get-MgServicePrincipal.
```

With those, I get almost everything, but important information are missing :

- When a SAML App has several IdentifierUris or ReplyUrls, I only get the list, not the one that is marked as "primary" in the Azure Portal ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wv2jm.png))
- For OAuth Applications, I'm able to know is the app uses SPA, Native or Web Redirect Uris and if the app uses the Implicit Flow. But how would I know if the app uses Client Credentials (OAuth Services), or Authorization Code with PKCE ?
- For SAML Applications, I'm trying to retrieve the Claims & Attributes. When they are applied to the app with a "Claim mapping Policy", I'm able to do so. But when they are changed directly in the Azure Portal (see above), I do not retrieve that information :

[Changing Attributes & Claims in the Azure Portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WezC.png)

Thanks for considering my request.

Comment: What do you mean by "the one that is marked as "primary" in the Azure Portal"? I didn't see any of them is marked as "primary". Could you provide a screenshot? Whether the app uses Client Credentials (OAuth Services), or Authorization Code with PKCE cannot be found with the OAuth Applications.

Comment: I edited my post with a screenshot, thanks for your answer

Comment: Got it! Unfortunately the SAML app information you mentioned are not available in Azure AD Powershell and MS Graph Powershell. I try to capture the request and it's using `https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api` endpoint in Azure portal. Similar question I answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65613441/azure-rest-call-to-get-enterprise-application-single-sign-on-information/65622868#65622868.

Comment: So it means that I would need to call this endpoint ? I do not find how to call it with the right headers.. I've seen it being used here : https://o365blog.com/aadinternals/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to retrieve some information with the following Microsoft undisclosed API :
`"https://main.iam.ad.ext.azure.com/api"`, especially most information for SAML Applications

How to gain access to this hidden API is discussed here : https://www.lieben.nu/liebensraum/2020/04/calling-graph-and-other-apis-silently-for-an-mfa-enabled-account/